# topic level overrides for Kafka topic do not work

Tags: apache-kafka

I have set up several topic-level overrides for one of my Kafka topics, and when I describe the topic, I see:

`Topic:xxx    PartitionCount:x    ReplicationFactor:x    Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,retention.ms=3600000,segment.ms=3600000`

but when I check the logs, it seems that these topic-level configs are not being followed. More specifically, logs are not being rolled every hour. I assume that broker configs are still being used, which have retention.ms/segment.ms set to 7 days, and segment.bytes set to 1G.

Comment: Can you describe how you specified the overrides for the topic ?

Comment: @MickaelMaison I was using the script `/opt/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --topic xxx --config segment.bytes=358300000 --zookeeper localhost:2181`, and also tried using yahoo's `kafka-manager` to update the configs.

Comment: Did you mean all partitions' logs did not honor these settings?

Comment: @amethystic Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `kafka-configs.sh` script instead of `kafka-topics.sh` when using Kafka version 0.9.0 and up.

> Altering topic configuration from the kafka-topics.sh script
>   (kafka.admin.TopicCommand) has been deprecated. Going forward, please
>   use the kafka-configs.sh script (kafka.admin.ConfigCommand) for this
>   functionality.

For example:

`bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name my-topic --alter --add-config max.message.bytes=128000`

See [Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).